# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod set form field data type like cURL

Tags: powershell, curl

I am using Powershell 7.3.1 and Invoke-RestMethod. I need to submit a form to a server but one of the fields needs to be typed as JSON or the request will fail. In cURL, this can be accomplished by appending `;type=application/json` to the field but that doesn't seem to work with Invoke-RestMethod.

In cURL, submitting a form with types would look something like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8082/csv-as-input' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'file=@"C:/Users/test/task-b5cfe19-input.csv"' \
--form 'json="{\"name\": \"Test\",\"jobType\": \"BATCH_FILE\",\"runMode\": \"VALIDATE\",\"config\": {\"branchId\": \"12345\",\"trustedSource\": true}}";type=application/json'
```

In this case, the `json` form element is treated as a JSON string because of the `;type=application/json` at the end.

I have tried to write the Powershell version using the new `-Form` parameter:

```
$CreateJobForm = @{
    'file' = Get-Item -Path 'C:\Users\test\task-b5cfe19-input.csv'
    'json' = '{"name": "Test","jobType": "BATCH_FILE","runMode": "VALIDATE","config": {"branchId": "12345","trustedSource": true}};type=application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri http://localhost:8082/csv-as-input -Form $CreateJobForm
```

The cURL command works but the Powershell version fails because it is coming across as a `text/plain` type.

Is there a way to type the `json` field as JSON in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -ContentType parameter to specify the content type of the request body as multipart/form-data, and then use the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet to convert the JSON object to a JSON string and include it in the form data.

```
    $json = @{
    'name' = 'Test'
    'jobType' = 'BATCH_FILE'
    'runMode' = 'VALIDATE'
    'config' = @{
        'branchId' = '12345'
        'trustedSource' = $true
    }
}

$CreateJobForm = @{
    'file' = Get-Item -Path 'C:\Users\test\task-b5cfe19-input.csv'
    'json' = (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $json)
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri http://localhost:8082/csv-as-input -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Form $CreateJobForm
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  The `json` field is still going across the wire as a `text/plain` object after the suggested changes.  Any other ideas?